# UIPickerview passing text to label in another view

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I just started learning so take it easy on me...

The goal is to take the text value of the selected row in the picker and display that in a label in another view.

Right now I'm having difficulty storing the string value, everything compiles and loads but the label in the second view remains blank. De-noobify me please.

```
//String taken from selected pickerview line and stored in selectedstring
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Selected: %@",[_platforms objectAtIndex:row]];
Selectedstring.text = string;
```

On "next view" button press:

```
- (IBAction)NextView:(id)sender {
SecondView *secondview = [[SecondView alloc]init];

self.SecondViewData = secondview;
SecondViewData.passedValue = Selectedstring.text;

[self presentViewController:secondview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then in the "viewdidload" area of the next view I have:

```
label.text = passedValue;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to write below statement in ViewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

label.text = passedValue;

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    SecondView *secondview = [[SecondView alloc]init];

self.SecondViewData = secondview;
SecondViewData.passedValue = Selectedstring.text;

[self presentViewController:secondview animated:YES completion:nil];
secondview.label.text = passedValue;  //passing values to uilabel
}
```